# Differentiate complex function with respect to complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider the function $f(x,y)=\cos^2(x+iy^2)$

I'm asked to differentiate this function with respect to $z=x+iy$.

My idea would have been to look at $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and use that to calculate the partial derivative. However I get inconsistent results when I try this differential equation with $y$ instead of $x$.

Also I don't see a possibility to substitute the $z$ into $f$ due to the square of $y$.

I'd be glad if someone could show me how to solve this!

Comment: which rule are you trying to apply here? If it's the chain rule you are missing the 
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}\frac{\partial \bar z}{\partial x}$ part, but that's not what you are after. You want to use, if you want to go that way at all, $$\frac{\partial }{\partial z} =\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} \frac{\partial }{\partial x} +\frac{\partial y}{\partial z} \frac{\partial }{\partial y}$$ (I may have missed a factor $\pm i$ here).  Alternatively, express $x$ and $y$ with the help of $z$ and $\bar z$. The latter you must not ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the complex
$w=x+iy^2$.
Using Wirtinger derivatives,
$$
\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}
=
\frac12
\left[
\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}
-i
\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}
\right]
=
\frac12
\left[
1-i
(2iy)
\right]
=
\frac12
\left[
1+2y
\right]
$$
and similarly
$$
\frac{\partial w}{\partial z^*}
=
\frac12
\left[
1-2y
\right]
$$
The differential writes
$$
dw
=
\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}dz+
\frac{\partial w}{\partial z^*}dz^*
$$

Because $f(w)=\cos^2 w$ is analytic,
it holds
\begin{eqnarray*}
df 
&=& - \sin(2w) dw \\
&=& - \frac12 \sin(2w) 
\left[
\left( 1+2y \right)dz + \left(1+2y \right)dz^*
\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
Finally, we conclude that
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}
=
- \frac12 \sin(2w) \left( 1+2y \right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

For finding the complex derivative, the function has to satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations.
$$ 
f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)
$$
$$
\implies f'(z)=u_x+iv_x=v_y-iu_y
$$

This means $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$.

Alternatively, you can apply the Wirtinger derivative as follows.
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2} \Big( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Big)
$$

You may check out more info on wiki:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think you’ve miswritten the Cauchy Riemann equations.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I modified my answer above.

Comment: The Cauchy-Riemann equations tell you, whether a function is holomorphic. Whether that's true or not has to be verified in this case. Regardless of that you can still differentiate the function wrt $z$.